# Can I access the lower level bokeh 'plotting' interface from a higher level 'charts' object?

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

*Note from Maintainers: This questions refers to the obsolete `bokeh.charts` API which no longer exists. For up to date information about categorical heatmaps, see:*

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#heat-maps

---

---

***OBSOLETE:***

I used the HeatMap example here to produce the chart below
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.0/docs/user_guide/charts.html#heatmap

[image]

And now want to:

**1) Add x & y axis labels**

**2) Reverse the range of the y axis**

**3) Put the x axis at the top (not the bottom)**

Are these possible via the handle p to the HeatMap?

If not, is it possible to get back to the figure handle via p?

Code snip below:

```
from bokeh.charts import HeatMap, output_file, show
import pandas as pd

output_file('heatmap.html')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(apples=[4, 5, 8],
        bananas=[1, 2, 4],
        pears=[6, 5, 4]),
    index=['2012', '2013', '2014'])

p = HeatMap(df, title='Fruits')


# 1) Want to label the axis
p.xlabel('This is a test label') # This does not appear

# 2) Want to reverse the Y axis: 2012:2014 to 2014:2012
p.y_range(start=2014, end=2012) # TypeError: 'FactorRange' object is not callable

# 3) Want to move the x axis (apples, bananas & pears) to the top, just under the title 'fruits'
# ?

show(p)
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to access figure properties from a high level chart like HeatMap. In case anyone else wonders about this, instead of using HeatMap, here is what I did:

1. I had to create a ColumnDataSource,
2. Define a colormap,
3. Create a figure: p = figure(...)
4. Then use the rect method create each block individually with the appropriate color from the colormap

After that, the 3 things I wanted to do were possible:

**1) Add x & y axis labels**

```
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'my X label'

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'my y label'
```

**2) Reverse the range of the y axis**

```
if y_names is the list of y categories:

p = figure(...., y_range=list(reversed(y_names), ...)
```

**3) Put the x axis at the top (not the bottom)**

```
p = figure(..., x_axis_location="above", ...)
```

This isn't pretty, but it works.